# Convert number to words in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, type-conversion, numeric

Is there a way in ssrs to convert a numeric value to actual text words in SSRS?  i know there is a "towords" function in Crystal Reports, though I am not sure if it is standard, i.e. may require some sort of API download.  is this functionality available in SSRS?  If not, can the conversion be performed in SQL Server?  My reports run off of a SQL Server stored procedure.

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried =CStr(NumberField)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server to return your dataset, then you can use the following function

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_CurrencyToWords] (@Input numeric(15,2),@Currency tinyint) 
RETURNS varchar (8000) 
AS 
BEGIN 

DECLARE @CharInput char(15) 
--Pad the input
SET @CharInput = RIGHT('0000000000000' + convert(varchar(15),@Input),15) 

DECLARE @Counter tinyint
SET @Counter = 1

DECLARE @InputSub varchar(3)
DECLARE @Group tinyint
DECLARE @Output varchar (8000)

--Get words for each group with some logic for concatenation
WHILE @Counter <= len(@CharInput)-2
BEGIN
SET @InputSub = replace(substring(@CharInput,@Counter,3),'.','')
SET @Group = (len(@CharInput)-@Counter+1)/3

SET @Output = 
ISNULL(@Output,'') 
+ CASE 
WHEN (@Group = 1 AND @InputSub <> 0 AND @Input >= 1.00) OR (@Group = 2 AND @InputSub BETWEEN 1 AND 99 AND @Input > 1000) THEN 'And '
ELSE ''
END
+ CASE
WHEN (@Group = 1 AND @InputSub = 0 AND @Input >= 1.00) OR (@Group = 2 AND @InputSub = 0 AND @Input < 1.00) THEN ''
ELSE [dbo].[udf_CurrencyToWordsSub](@InputSub,@Group,@Currency)
END

SET @Counter = @Counter + 3
CONTINUE
END

--Fix plurals and return a plain Zero if required
SET @Output = 
CASE 
WHEN right(@CharInput,2) = '01' THEN replace(@Output,'~','')
ELSE replace(@Output,'~','s')
END
SET @Output = 
CASE 
WHEN @Input < 2 THEN replace(@Output,'#','')
ELSE replace(@Output,'#','s')
END

RETURN ltrim(rtrim(@Output))
END
```

Then you can call the function like this

```
 select dbo.[udf_CurrencyToWords] (8990.03,3)
```

result

```
 Eight Thousand, Nine Hundred And Ninety Dollars And Three Cents
```

Just change the @currency for the currency you want

```
select dbo.[udf_CurrencyToWords] (8990.03,1)
Eight Thousand, Nine Hundred And Ninety Pounds And Three Pence
```